# Cors origin still allowing requests from other origins

Tags: cors, nestjs

I have an elixir phoenix app in which i make requests to an external nestjs api backend. I want this api to only accept request from the elixir app. I'm currently using:

```
app.enableCors({ origin: "http://localhost:4000" })
```

on the nestjs api to fulfill this requirement. That is the port the elixir/phoenix app is on. But even if i change it to port 3747 (or whatever other type of url, it still receives requests from the app on port 4000, which it shouldn't then, right?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: No. CORS is not a defence.

Comment: Where is the fetch request to the API executed? Directly in the browser or on your phoenix server? CORS headers are only respected by browsers, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
So when your server executes the request the CORS headers will likely be ignored.